# Finding information about GPG keys?

Tags: gnupg

I once found out that I can do that [here](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/). But I recently tried to find information about:

```
$ gpg --search-key B188E2B695BD4743
gpg: data source: http://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371
(1)     DEB.SURY.ORG Automatic Signing Key <deb@sury.org>
          3072 bit RSA key B188E2B695BD4743, created: 2019-03-18, expires: 2024-02-16
Keys 1-1 of 1 for "B188E2B695BD4743".  Enter number(s), N)ext, or Q)uit >
```

And it doesn't seem like the information provided by the [service](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?search=DEB.SURY.ORG+Automatic+Signing+Key&op=vindex) (web interface) is up to date. `gpg --search-key` is probably okay. But the web interface provides more information. And you can search by name/email. (And well, it's unexpected that pressing a digit makes `gpg` import the key.)

What is the recommended way? Was the service abandoned?

Comment: The main problem of public key servers is that everybody can upload keys. So when searching for an email address you never know who uploaded the key, can be the owner of the mail address or can be someone else.

Comment: @Robert Unless you search on [keys.openpgp.org](https://keys.openpgp.org/about)?